"Reviews completed today" looks wrong on Staging Ground questions

When I go to a question in the SG (example), the Reviews completed today styling is broken.
It might be related to the recent sidebar changes. Note that this works fine on the main SG page, but when you click onto a question, it renders wrong.
Can it be fixed?

Despite the link to report a bug directly underneath the box, I prefer Meta in this case.

Was this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405011 absolutely necessary? It's not necessarily a bad change, but now bug after bug needs fixing. Developers could work on more important stuff that community actually asked for. Screaming into the void.

Hum, DV'ed for not mentioning your FCI... No-repro on FF133 + Win10, Screenshot from your 'CATIA' Example... (Or I don't understand what you mean by "styling"...?)

@chivracq Thanks for the comment. That's what it looks like for me too (Firefox, Linux), but compare it to how that box looks on this page.

Ah alright, your "this page" is the 'Proposed questions' Page/Tab from the main 'SG'-page, and yep indeed, the "styling" is different... Boah!, no big deal I would think, the content is the same and correct... // More disturbing (= useless!) I would think is the Value of the "Badge progress" for the 'Daily Practice' (difficult to keep up when to use Capitals or not btw) Badge, ... which is always about 24h "too late", => Example just right now, while I did my 2 Reviews more than 10h ago...

@chivracq your style of commenting never stops amusing me (and never gets easier to understand). Anyway, it is a big deal. If it was just about content, we'd have created every webpage like reader view.

Ah OK, @M-- (hum, lost your temp 'Double-Dash' apparently), well, changing the Font/Size/Thickness/Shading/Colour of one String on one page is not a "Bug" for me... (... well unless Pix-Size <60 or >500, of course). 'SO' is the buggiest Site I've ever come across (only surpassed by 'Facebook' currently, since about 1 year), I could list 50, possibly 100 "things" on 'SO' that are much buggier and more frustrating than this gentle Font (Size) change... Let the Devs have "a bit of fun" from time to time... (Or call it an Experiment maybe...)

@chivracq I doubt that they're having fun. And I am not saying it should be addressed tmrw, as a matter of fact, I'd rather leave this one be, and let them work on hundreds of other requests and bugs that are years or a decade old at this point. Nonetheless, reporting such bugs is hardly counterproductive. Devs can decide what to address and what to defer, as they have throughout the years. Cheers.

I don't see this on Chromium (Brave, v1.73.97) on Win11.

I can reproduce it on Firefox 133.0.3 on Ubuntu 24.10. I think it also happened in the past.
